# Matrix addition using file input and output in java

Tags: java, matrix, file-io

I need to make a matrix addition using file input and output in java. If my intput file contains the following where 2 is row and 3 is column, I need to make an output file which contains the addition of those two matrix. I need to use Scanner to take those matrix from input file, but I don't know how to start it . Can anyone help solving this problem?

2 3

4 5 6
7 8 9

1 2 3 
0 1 2

Comment: 456 is 1st row of matrix 1 and 789 is 2nd row of matrix 1. And 123 is 1st row of matrix 2 and 012 is 2nd row of matrix 2.

Answer (score 0):

use `Scanner` to read from input file and `FileWriter` to write in output file

```
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("path of input file"));
        /*
          read data using for-loop and scanner methods
          and store them in some 2D integer arrays
          at last write them to a file using 

          FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("path of output file"), false);

          in FileWriter constructor ,if you want to append data to output file, use true instead of false
        */
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```